# How can I get array key => errorMessage from $violations. Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

Here is my code

```
 $arParams = $request->all();

    $validator = Validation::createValidator();

    $groups = new GroupSequence(['Default', 'custom']);

    $constraint = new Assert\Collection([
        'name' => new Assert\Length(['min' => 2]),
        'city' => new Assert\Length(['min' => 2]),
        'email' => new Assert\Email(),
        'phone' => new Assert\Length(['min' => 18]),
        'message' => new Assert\NotNull()
    ]);

    $violations = $validator->validate($arParams, $constraint, $groups);
```

If i get some errors, how can I get an array like
['name' => not enough symbols, 'email' => wrong email]?

I tried to use foreach on $violations but cant find all the methods of its elements Phpstorm sign $violation as mixed. I found only $violation->getMessage() and ->getCode()

Comment: there is no way to get a, i would say, perfect error array. You need to loop through your violations and get your messages with `$violation->getMessage()` . Otherwise you want the constraint object you can access it with `$violation->getConstraint()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to read this article https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

If validation fails, a non-empty list of errors (class [ConstraintViolationList](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.2/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/ConstraintViolationList.php)) is returned.

So you can get your list this way:

```
if ($violations->count() > 0) {
    $formatedViolationList = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $violations->count(); $i++) {
            $violation = $violations->get($i);
            $formatedViolationList[] = array($violation->getPropertyPath() => $violation->getMessage());
        }
}
```

Couple explanations. We use methods from violation api `count()` or get a number of violations, and after in for loop we use `get($i)` for get every violation by index. After we use `getPropertyPath()` for get path (name of your property) and `getMessage()` for get message.

Comment: You don't need a for loop, just do a foreach on the `$violations` variable.